Env variable visible in Vite build production environement
I have only a simple frontend React/Vite application (used for AWS Cognito login), no backend.
All my environment variables are in an .env file prefixed with "VITE_".
How can I keep them secrets when I build the application (vite build) ?
Right now, they appear into the dist/assets files and thus become readable into the browser, which makes sense but certainly not what I want.
(some of them are credentials & password by example to access to AWS Cognito pool).
Thanks

You're going to need a simple backend to act like a proxy between your front end and the various services you need keys for. There's no way to hide them on the front end.

When building a frontend application with Vite, any environment variables prefixed with VITE_ are exposed to the client-side code. This is by design, as these variables need to be available at build time to configure your application. However, this means sensitive information, such as credentials and passwords, should never be stored in these environment variables because they will be exposed in the final build.
you may set up a simple backend server to handle sensitive operations. This way, you can keep secrets on the server and never expose them to the client.

thanks a lot for your fast answer, I wanted to avoid the backend but I get it ! This way, is there a best practice to do it ? because if it's just API callbacks to get the values of my environment variables (stocked in back side this time), the issue is now in the callback response where it's still possible to see the variables.

by example : use of axios to get "http://localhost/getVal1" returns {"Result": "SecretValue"} which is visible in the browser console/Network/Response.

You wouldn't want secrets to be sent to the front end, ever. Your front end would send a request to your back end, which knows the secrets and can talk to AWS resources directly. That way, your AWS creds are never sent to the front end.

oki, got it, thanks everyone !

I'm back on my question. What about the Amplify.configure() data ? If I use a backend callback to get my configuration, the values are displayed into the callback Response. Otherwise if I use a json file stocked into the interface, the values are displayed in my dist/assets files.
